# "hostname resolves to the loopback address" error in Matlab Distributed Computing

Tags: matlab, hostname, loopback

Windows 10 Pro, Active Directory. I'm trying to run Mathworks Matlab Distributed Computing. The software communicates with a process on another computer but stops and says "hostname resolves to the loopback address".  Mathworks has had me try a few things. Assigned the loopback address 127.0.0.1 to host name in the HOSTS file. Assigned the actual ( DHCP ) IP address of hostname in the HOSTS file. Removed IPv6. Set an environment variable FNP_IP_ENV=1. None of these had any effect. Has the error "hostname resolves to the loopback address" come up in any other software?

Comment: Please check mathworks.com and the solutions to this kind of problems.

Comment: The Mathworks support team has been unable to solve this problem. It has been escalated to the development team.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and was able to resolve it. My cluster is a mix of Linux (Ubuntu 18.04), Windows 7, and Windows 10 Pro. I initially had the problem that hostnames, when ping-ed from the same machine, would resolve to the ipv4 loopback address 127.0.0.1. This was fixed on Linux machines and windows 7 by adding a line to the hosts file on each machine that was of the form 192.168.0.XX hostname,
where XX is the actual reserved IP ending for that machine on my LAN, and hostname is the hostname of the machine in question. If you already added that and are still getting the ipv4 loopback after ping hostname, you should check that windows is not ignoring your hosts file. Windows can ignore it if formatting, file permissions, whitespace, etc. are not just right. See https://serverfault.com/questions/452268/hosts-file-ignored-how-to-troubleshoot  for more troubleshooting about this issue.
One simple test to see if it is being ignored is to add another entry of the form:

```
192.168.0.XX hostname2
```

i.e. (some other made up IP address on the network) (made up hostname)

and then ping hostname2. If the IP is made up, you won't get a reply, but you should still be able to see that the name is resolving to whatever IP you put in the hosts file. If it does not, hosts is not being processed. hosts file changes should take effect immediately.

I also had a similar issue on Windows 10 even after my hosts file was correctly set with the ipv4 address, except that in this case it was resolving to the ipv6 loopback address ::1 even though I had disabled ipv6. Apparently the ipv6 loopback network adapter is always active even if ipv6 is disabled for external LAN traffic.   I was able to resolve this by setting ipv4 as the preferred protocol for the machine by editing the prefix policy using netsh in a command window.

In my case, the commands I used were:

```
netsh int ipv6 set prefixpolicy ::/0 32 1
netsh int ipv6 set prefixpolicy ::1/128 33 0
```

These set the ipv6 and ipv6 loopback to be lower priority (32 and 33, respectively) than ipv4 default priority (35).

Here are the standard prefix policies before modification, with ipv6 at the top:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>netsh interface ipv6 show prefixpolicies
Querying active state...

Precedence  Label  Prefix
----------  -----  --------------------------------
        50      0  ::1/128
        40      1  ::/0
        35      4  ::ffff:0:0/96
        30      2  2002::/16
         5      5  2001::/32
         3     13  fc00::/7
         1     11  fec0::/10
         1     12  3ffe::/16
         1      3  ::/96
```

Here are the policies after the above 2 commands, with ipv6 just below ipv4:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>netsh interface ipv6 show prefixpolicies
Querying active state...

Precedence  Label  Prefix
----------  -----  --------------------------------
        35      4  ::ffff:0:0/96
        33      0  ::1/128
        32      1  ::/0
        30      2  2002::/16
         5      5  2001::/32
         3     13  fc00::/7
         1     11  fec0::/10
         1     12  3ffe::/16
         1      3  ::/96
```

This thread has more info about prefix policies:
https://superuser.com/questions/436574/ipv4-vs-ipv6-priority-in-windows-7

After these changes, I checked that a ping of each machine's own hostname, when done from the same machine, returns the reserved ipv4 network address and re-ran the "test connectivity" tests from the Matlab parallel server admin center and had no more errors. My cluster worked without errors after that.